# 酵: jiào vs. xiào

Tags: pronunciation, history

I'm always hearing the pronunciations jiào and xiào being used interchangeably by native speakers for the character: 酵.

- What's the deal?
- Is there a standardized pronunciation for 酵?
- What's the history behind the different pronunciations?
- Or is it just a case of 四川人生得憨?

Comment: What's the story about 四川人生得憨?

Comment: @NS.X. 四川人生得憨，认字认半边, guess the pronunciation from half of the character (and get it wrong).

Comment: I have heard Singapore/Shanghai pronunciations of the word, and I have literally never heard the "jiao" version before. Thanks for the TIL.

Comment: wow I've never heard jiao4 either for that character, always xiao4.  Interesting.  校 can be read jiao4 in 校对 etc, and people mix it up (as xiao4) sometimes as well, though maybe that's just being too used to the xiao4 reading.  I wonder why there seems to be a relationship between the two sounds for characters incorporating 交 and 孝 as phonetics.  BTW really like the bit about Sichuan people ;)

Comment: It reads **xiào** also in our Xi'an dialect and most northern areas. The pronounciation of some characters in Mandarin are not so logical sometimes. For example: 核 reads **hái** in our dialect, the same as 亥, 孩, 咳, 骇 and 氦, but different tones, so I prefer **xiào** than **jiào**, though the later one is the standard.

Comment: A quick survey of cooking shows on YouTube indicates that "jiào" appears to be the standard.

Comment: @賈可 咳 is hai? Really? So, 咳嗽 is hai shou?

Comment: @joehua I forgot that 咳 could read both **hāi** and **ké**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standardized pronunciation is "jiào", it not "xiào" in the word "发酵." But in south of China, like Taiwan, people read it as "xiào" which is not standard.

I think that because of the two pronunciation is so similar that people always read it as "xiào".

发酵 means 有机物由于某些菌或酶而分解称“发酵”。能使有机物发酵的真菌称“酵母菌”。亦称“酵母”、“酿母”。

Comment: Taiwan standard for 酵 is [`xiào`](http://dict.mini.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/gdic/gsweb.cgi?o=ddictionary&searchid=D0001470&framefile=frame04.htm&).

Comment: Never been there just see in TV or movie.:)

Comment: @Stan Which standard would you say is most **traditional** then? Mainland or TW? Middle Chinese readings for 交、教、酵 all seem to be a variation (tone wise) on *kaew* which translates to something closer to jiao than xiao.

Comment: @user3306356 sorry I know very little about phonology, so I can't answer this question :)

Comment: You would people would not mix up the pronunciation since one sounds the same as the word for yelling Jiao and the other is xiao like laughing lol

Comment: @Mou某 If you check 漢典, which cites 康熙字典, you'd find 【廣韻】古孝切【集韻】居效切，音敎。

Answer (score 2):

I agress with @zoosuck, the standardized pronunciation is jiào. but in different dialect like Sichuanese people use xiào

example: 发酵, 酵母片, 发酵了以后的葡萄

Answer (score 1):

酵 pronounced as jiào.
 it is a pictophonogram, the left part telling the meaning, the right 
 part telling pronunciation.

孝, xiào, filial piety, is a very important character for Chinese. All 
 Chinese know it. So when the first time they saw a new character 酵, 
their first instict is to read it as xiào. actually, it should be read 
 as jiào.

by the way, 孝 is the look of a child or young child supporting his 
 father or other senior generations.

Answer (score 0):

You have to realize first that Mandarin is a much younger(roughly 600 years) language than the other much older Chinese dialect.  This is why all the older dialects have 'xiao4' as reading.  酵 and 孝 are both hau in Hakka and Cantonese with different tone.

The same can be seen in words like 粘 and 黏 being pronounced as nian2(TW) or nim1(Cantonese), niam1(Hakka), liam/niam(minnanese),  while mainland mandarin would read it as 'zhan1'

So if you're interested in learning the culture, then 'xiao4' makes more sense, if you're trying to just communicate then 'jiao4' is the current standard unless if you're in Taiwan and some southern parts of China(maybe?).

Comment: I always pronounce 粘 as zhan though 國語詞典 has only nian for this character. According to 漢典, 酵 in hakka can be pronounced as gau or hau. Some places have both gau and hau pronunciations, some has only gau, and no place has only hau.

Answer (score -1):

this is a Polyphonic word, like English, there are so many Polyphonic words in Chinese too.
here are some other common used Polyphonic words: http://www.maxmandarin.com/lesson.php?lesson=wordlesson10